# Inkscape Generate SVG 1.1-compliant arrowheads instead of using 1.2 auto-start-reverse

Tags: svg, inkscape

In Inkscape 1.1, I'm not seeing an option to save to a strictly SVG v1.1 formatted file. I've seen screenshots of past versions that had a checkbox for this option.  In renderers using batik 1.14, such as Apache FOP, Batik Squiggle, and OxygenXML, I'm seeing errors of the nature:

> (1) The attribute "fill" represents an invalid CSS value
> ("context-stroke"). Original message: The "context-stroke" identifier
> is not a valid value for the "fill" property.
>
> (2) SVG Error: For input string: "auto-start-reverse"

From source such as:

```
  <marker id="marker16573" orient="auto-start-reverse" refX="5" refY="3">
   <path d="m10 3-10 3v-6z" fill="context-stroke" stroke="#000"/>
  </marker>
```

The auto-start-reverse option for the orient attribute wasn't added until SVG 1.2.

So how can I get a strict SVG 1.1 output from Inkscape. I've tried the Plain and Optimized SVG formats and they still include these attributes.

I also see errors about aria-labels in other instances depending on which SVG Optimizer I try.

Is there a reliable tool to generate a strict SVG 1.1 file from a 1.2 file?

Comment: FWIW auto-start-reverse was added in SVG 2, not SVG 1.2

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the versions. If I replace auto-start-reverse with auto, the arrow heads are incorrect. If I knew what the 1.1 equivalent was, I could run it through as XSL transform.

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences, enable the option to 'Use correct marker direction in SVG 1.1 renderers' (and potentially the one for the color, too).

(just type 'marker' into the search field to find it)

When saving, enable the option to export in SVG 1.1 format.